# How to set authentication headers dynamically in soapUI?

Tags: soapui

I have around 50 test steps included in my test suite. Currently I am setting the authentication headers (`auth_token`, `id_token` and `nonce`) values for each test step manually. How can I set the values for all the test steps at once?

It would be great if you could help me set the dynamic headers in test suite level.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

If the values are the same for each test step, you could set custom properties at the the test suite level and refer to the properties in your headers:

[image: Using property expansion]

See [Working with Properties](https://www.soapui.org/docs/functional-testing/properties/working-with-properties.html%20%22Working%20with%20Properties) for more details.